# ScaleAnimation duplicate as background

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, scale

I want to shrink a button/checkbox based on an animation. For this I use the following code and this works well:

```
                val scaler = ScaleAnimation(
                    1.0f,
                    0.0f,
                    1.0f,
                    1.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f,
                )
                
                scaler.duration = 10000
                kitchen.startAnimation(scaler)
```

However, I would like the button/checkbox to create itself as a 2nd layer and then run the animation. So that you have an overlay on the "normal button" that is then behind it. How do you do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please follow StackOverFlow guidelines to ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you question, the easiest way to accomplish what you want is to create two buttons - one atop the other. The one underneath would normally be invisible but would be made visible when the animation starts on the top button. Here is an example:

[image]

XML for the layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUnder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/buttonOver"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/buttonOver"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/buttonOver"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/buttonOver" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the code:

```
val buttonUnder = binding.buttonUnder
buttonUnder.isVisible = false
val buttonOver = binding.buttonOver
buttonOver.setOnClickListener {
    val scaler = ScaleAnimation(
        1.0f,
        0.0f,
        1.0f,
        1.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        0.5f,
    )
    buttonUnder.isVisible = true
    scaler.duration = 10000
    buttonOver.startAnimation(scaler)
}
```

Comment: Alright thanks, I'm going to see if this works, just have to rewrite some code because we don't create the checkboxes in XML, we create them programmatically. Will update you later on this

Comment: The problem is that we have in button 1 some content that should not disappear. Because you put button 2 above it, this will no longer be visible. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Do you have an example or can be more explicit?

Comment: @Cheticamp Your example for illustration. In button 1 the word "button" disappears/shrinks. This should not happen what I want is that literally only the background color plays the animation and so all the content like in your case "button" does not shrinks with it.

Comment: Consider making the front view with the word "button" with a transparent background. Place the view that will shrink behind the front view and positioned such that it looks like the front view's background. Now run the animation on the back view. To use the front view's actual background, you would need to consider a background drawable that can be smaller than the front view such as an inset or bitmap drawable and run the animation on that.